# HTML submit button in textarea

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="mailto:bleh@bleh" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
            <p>
                Name: <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="40" style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-background-clip: padding;-moz-background-clip: padding;background-clip: padding-box;-webkit-border-radius: 0;-moz-border-radius: 0;-ms-border-radius: 0;-o-border-radius: 0;border-radius: 0;-webkit-appearance: none;background-color: white;border: 1px solid;border-color: #848484 #c1c1c1 #e1e1e1;color: black;outline: 0;margin: 0;padding: 2px 3px;text-align: left;font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial, &quot;Liberation Sans&quot;, FreeSans, sans-serif;height: 1.8em;vertical-align: top">
            </p>
            <p>
                Vorname: <input name="Vorname" type="text" id="Vorname" size="40" style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-background-clip: padding;-moz-background-clip: padding;background-clip: padding-box;-webkit-border-radius: 0;-moz-border-radius: 0;-ms-border-radius: 0;-o-border-radius: 0;border-radius: 0;-webkit-appearance: none;background-color: white;border: 1px solid;border-color: #848484 #c1c1c1 #e1e1e1;color: black;outline: 0;margin: 0;padding: 2px 3px;text-align: left;font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial, &quot;Liberation Sans&quot;, FreeSans, sans-serif;height: 1.8em;vertical-align: top">
            </p>
            <p>
                E-mail address: <input name="E-mail" type="text" id="E-mail" size="40" style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-background-clip: padding;-moz-background-clip: padding;background-clip: padding-box;-webkit-border-radius: 0;-moz-border-radius: 0;-ms-border-radius: 0;-o-border-radius: 0;border-radius: 0;-webkit-appearance: none;background-color: white;border: 1px solid;border-color: #848484 #c1c1c1 #e1e1e1;color: black;outline: 0;margin: 0;padding: 2px 3px;text-align: left;font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial, &quot;Liberation Sans&quot;, FreeSans, sans-serif;height: 1.8em;vertical-align: top">
            </p>
            <p>
                Comment: <textarea value=" " name="Comment" cols="55" rows="5" id="Comment" style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-background-clip: padding;-moz-background-clip: padding;background-clip: padding-box;-webkit-border-radius: 0;-moz-border-radius: 0;-ms-border-radius: 0;-o-border-radius: 0;border-radius: 0;-webkit-appearance: none;background-color: white;border: 1px solid;border-color: #848484 #c1c1c1 #e1e1e1;color: black;outline: 0;margin: 0;padding: 2px 3px;text-align: left;font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial, &quot;Liberation Sans&quot;, FreeSans, sans-serif;height: auto;vertical-align: top;min-height: 40px;overflow: auto;resize: vertical;width: 100%">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" style="-webkit-appearance: none;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;-ms-border-radius: 4px;-o-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-background-clip: padding;-moz-background-clip: padding;background-clip: padding-box;background: #ddd url(../images/button.png?1298351022) repeat-x;background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);border: 1px solid;border-color: #ddd #bbb #999;cursor: pointer;color: #333;display: inline-block;font: bold 12px/1.3 &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, &quot;Liberation Sans&quot;, FreeSans, sans-serif;outline: 0;overflow: visible;margin: 0;padding: 3px 10px;text-shadow: white 0 1px 1px;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: top;width: auto">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why does this put the submit button html into the comment section? I have tried something i found on stack overflow value=" " however that has not fixed the problem

Comment: first of all stop using inline styles and use separate css which makes your code readable.

Comment: you're not actually closing the textarea. add `</textarea>` after the opening tag, you'll be fine. and yes, please for the love of krishnu move your inline styles to external CSS.

Comment: They can't be, it's a for a friend who is using a site that allows html in the content area, but they won't let you upload your own css file. The wrapping html head and body isn't going to be used, so i can't link in a stylesheet either. Thanks Tilwin, i'll accept your answer as soon as overflow allows me to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't closed your `<textarea>` tag.

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/2TaCe/)